# How to replace a value in dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to change the value in `userInfo` with `userArray`. I tried to change the first value of dictionary by writing `Object.values(userInfo)[0] = userArray[0]` but it didn't work. Is there another way to change values in a dictionary?

```js
let userInfo = {'John': money(),'Mary': money(),'Bob': money()}

console.log('Before Dictionary:',userInfo)

let total = 0
let userArray = Object.values(userInfo); //To get dictionary values into array
userArray.forEach(doubleMoney) //Multiply array values by 2

function money(){
    randomMoney = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    return randomMoney
}
function doubleMoney(element,index,array){
    array[index] = element * 2
}

Object.values(userInfo)[0] = userArray[0] //Change the first value of dict to first value of array

console.log('Mutiplied array: ',userArray)
console.log('After Dictionary: ',userInfo);
```

Comment: Why not simply loop through the object and double each value like this: `for(let key in userInfo) userInfo[key] *= 2`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because the values are *primitives*  e.g. numbers, so when you create `userArray` you simply get a new array of numbers. Changing them has no impact on `userInfo` it contains no *references* to the `userInfo`, only *values*.

So to change the value in `userInfo`:

```js
// See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/885922
userInfo[firstKey] *= 2;
```

Note that the keys are not guaranteed to be (insertion) ordered depending on if you're on ES2015+ or if you're using strings or numbers as your keys. Assuming you're on ES2015+, recent browser, and your keys are strings, you can use:

```js
const firstKey = Object.keys(userInfo)[0]
```

For more info see [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/885922).

To change all the values, use [for... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```js
for (let user in userInfo) {
    userInfo[user] *= 2;
}
```

For more info, I recommend reading [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/885922).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const first_dict = { 'key_one': 'value_one', 'key_two': 'value_two' } 
const second_dict = { 'key_one': 'value_from_second_dict', 'key_three': 'value_three' }

const accumulative = {
  ...first_dict,
  ...second_dict
}

console.log(accumulative)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please console this line : Object.values(userInfo)[0] = userArray[0]
both are values, you can't assign a value to a value. value are primitive.
you can use this :

```
userInfo[Object.keys(userInfo)[0]] = userArray[0];
```